# Can I combine CSS for border width and color into one?

Tags: css

I would like to specify a top border with a width of 1px that is red. I was trying like this and it seems to work:

```
border-width: 1px 0px 0px;
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
```

However is there a way I can do this with just the one CSS statement and combine these two?

Note that I need to override a previous setting of border width so I can't just use border-top :-(

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
border-top: 1px solid #f00;
```

Comment: Yes - if it is not necessary to define the style and color for the other sides then this will suffice.

Comment: You can't specify a top border and reset the other borders in the same line, best bet would be to `border: 0;` before the above

Comment: @Andy - Sorry. I updated my question. I really need to be sure the other three borders are not visible.

Comment: @Marilou You can't do what you need in one line of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

According to [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands):

> The ‘border’ property is a shorthand property for setting the same
>   width, color, and style for all four borders of a box. Unlike the
>   shorthand ‘margin’ and ‘padding’ properties, **the ‘border’ property
>   cannot set different values on the four borders. To do so, one or more
>   of the other border properties must be used.**

However, on your situation setting just `border-top` would left other borders on default, which is `none`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention I need to override the previous border settings.

Comment: So the answer is: No. You cannot set different border width on each side of the element using `border` shorthand property.